# Printing substrings' patterns from a string in Python

Tags: python, string

The input to this problem is a string and has a specific form. For example if s is a string then inputs can be `s='3(a)2(b)' or s='3(aa)2(bbb)' or s='4(aaaa)'`. The output should be a string, that is the substring inside the brackets multiplied by numerical substring value the substring inside the brackets follows.
For example,

```
Input ='3(a)2(b)'
Output='aaabb'

Input='4(aaa)'
Output='aaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

and similarly for other inputs. The program should print an empty string for wrong or invalid inputs.

This is what I've tried so far

```
s='3(aa)2(b)'
p=''
q=''
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    #print(s[i],end='')

    if s[i]=='(':
        k=int(s[i-1])
        while(s[i+1]!=')'):
            p+=(s[i+1])
            i+=1
    if s[i]==')':
        q+=k*p

print(q)
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also to all that are going to down vote this question, please explain why.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and where exactly you are having trouble. A _copy-and-paste_ answer won't help you understand how it was solved.

Comment: I saw this problem in practice problems on strings. This is not a homework.

Comment: Even if it is not homework, you should make a fair attempt.

Comment: Here are some hints. You will want to separate out each section of: `<num>(<letters>)`. You could grab each these buy looking for a pattern like: `/\d+\(.+\)/`. Then you can multiply strings to get the output. For example for `3(a)` take you can do: `3*'a' => 'aaa'`.

Comment: I've was working on it for the past two hours. I'm able to print the correct output for '3(a)2(b)' but having problems with '3(aa)2(bbb)' and similar inputs

Comment: @KunalJain Please edit your question and provide with the code you've written so far.

Comment: @KunalJain Please provide that code then. That way we can let you know why it doesn't work and how to fix it.

Comment: @KanulJain: then you should share your attempt, so people can help *debugging* your attempt.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, I've shared my approach. Thanks.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I've shared my approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A oneliner would be:

```
''.join(int(y[0])*y[1] for y in (x.split('(') for x in Input.split(')')[:-1]))
```

It works like this. We take the input, and split on the close paren

```
In [1]: Input ='3(a)2(b)'

In [2]: a = Input.split(')')[:-1]

In [3]: a
Out[3]: ['3(a', '2(b']
```

This gives us the integer, character pairs we're looking for, but we need to get rid of the open paren, so for each `x` in `a`, we split on the open paren to get a two-element list where the first element is the int (as a string still) and the character. You'll see this in `b`

```
In [4]: b = [x.split('(') for x in a]

In [5]: b
Out[5]: [['3', 'a'], ['2', 'b']]
```

So for each element in `b`, we need to cast the first element as an integer with `int()` and multiply by the character.

```
In [6]: c = [int(y[0])*y[1] for y in b]

In [7]: c
Out[7]: ['aaa', 'bb']
```

Now we join on the empty string to combine them into one string with

```
In [8]: ''.join(c)
Out[8]: 'aaabb'
```

Comment: I think you should put the `int(..)` on the on the second argument. But that being said, this can still fail if the language is recursive (like `2(a2(b)a)`).

Comment: I disagree with both of you @WillemVanOnsem and @SpencerWieczorek. The int cast is absolutely in the right place, and I just tested with `13(a)12(b)` and it works fine. It was also never stated in the OP that they were looking for a recursive solution. Not sure why you're throwing downvotes around w/o testing...

Comment: @wpercy I up-voted, although you might want to add an explanation to your solution.

Comment: What is the use of '[:-1]' in 'a = Input.split(')')[:-1]'?

Comment: When you initially split on `)`, there is a third element (in my example) which is just the empty string. the `[:-1]` slice omits that last, unnecessary element. Another way to do that would be to include `if x` at the end of the list comprehension in line 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a =  re.findall(r'[\d]+', s)
b = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', s)
c = ''
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    c+=(int(i)*str(j))
print(c)
```

Comment: for this exaample ` s='3(aa)2(bbb)'` it extract numbers from input and store it like `[3, 2]` and extract strings like `[aa, bbb]` then simply using `zip` i multiply string with number and append it in a new string and it gives output what you want.   `3*'aa'` gives `aaaaaa` and `2*'bbb'` gives `bbbbbb` and append both string to get desired output `aaaaaabbbbbb`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it:

### Step 1: Simple case, getting the data out of a really simple template

Let's assume your template string is `3(a)`. That's the simplest case I could think of. We'll need to extract pieces of information from that string. The first one is the count of chars that will have to be rendered. The second is the char that has to be rendered.

You are in a case where regex are more than suited (hence, the use of [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module from python's standard library).

I won't do a full course on regex. You'll have to do that by our own. However, I'll explain quickly the step I used. So, `count` (the variable that holds the number of times we should render the char to render) is a digit (or several). Hence our first capturing group will be something like `(\d+)`. Then we have a char to extract that is enclosed by parenthesis, hence `\((\w+)\)` (I actually enable several chars to be rendered at once). So, if we put them together, we get `(\d+)\((\w+)\)`. For testing you can check [this](https://regex101.com/r/msVfoQ/1) out.

Applied to our case, a straight forward use of the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module is:

```py
import re

# Our template
template = '3(a)'

# Run the regex
match = re.search(r'(\d+)\((\w+)\)', template)
if match:
    # Get the count from the first capturing group
    count = int(match.group(1))

    # Get the string to render from the second capturing group
    string = match.group(2)

    # Print as many times the string as count was given
    print count * string
```

Output:

```
aaa
```

Yeah!

---

### Step 2: Full case, with several templates

Okay, we know how to do it for 1 template, how to do the same for several, for instance `3(a)4(b)`? Well... How would we do it "*by hand*"? We'd read the full template from left to right and apply each template one by one. Then this is what we'll do with python!

Hopefully for us the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module has a function just for that: `finditer`. It does exactly what we described above.

So, we'll do something like:

```
import re

# Our template
template = '3(a)4(b)'

# Iterate through found templates
for match in re.finditer(r'(\d+)\((\w+)\)', template):
    # Get the count from the first capturing group
    count = int(match.group(1))

    # Get the string to render from the second capturing group
    string = match.group(2)

    print count * string
```

Output:

```
aaa
bbbb
```

Okay... Just remains the combination of that stuff. We know we can put everything at each step in an array, and then join each items of this array at the end, no?

Let's do it!

```py
import re

template = '3(a)4(b)'

parts = []
for match in re.finditer(r'(\d+)\((\w+)\)', template):
    parts.append(int(match.group(1)) * match.group(2))

print ''.join(parts)
```

Output:

```
aaabbb
```

Yeah!

---

### Step 3: Final step, optimization

Because we can always do better, we won't stop. `for` loops are cool. But what I love (it's personal) about python is that there is so much stuff you can actually just write with one line! Is it the case here? Well yes :).

First we can remove the `for` loop and the `append` using a list comprehension:

```py
parts = [int(match.group(1)) * match.group(2) for match in re.finditer(r'(\d+)\((\w+)\)', template)]
rendered = ''.join(parts)
```

Finally, let's remove the two lines with `parts` populating and then `join` and let's do all that in a single line:

```py
import re

template = '3(a)4(b)'

rendered = ''.join(
    int(match.group(1)) * match.group(2) \
    for match in re.finditer(r'(\d+)\((\w+)\)', template))

print rendered
```

Output:

```
aaabbb
```

Yeah! Still the same output :).

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The value of 'p' should be refreshed after each iteration.

```
s='1(aaa)2(bb)'
p=''
q=''
i=0
while i<len(s):
    if s[i]=='(':
        k=int(s[i-1])
        p=''
        while(s[i+1]!=')'):
            p+=(s[i+1])
            i+=1
    if s[i]==')':
        q+=k*p
    i+=1

print(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not behaving the way I want it to behave. The problem here is the placement of 'p'. 'p' is the variable that adds the substring inside the (  )s. I'm  repeating the process even after sufficient adding is done. Placing 'p' inside the 'if' block will do the job.

```
s='2(aa)2(bb)'

q=''
for i in range(0,len(s)):

    if s[i]=='(':
        k=int(s[i-1])
        p=''

        while(s[i+1]!=')'):
            #print(i,'first time')
            p+=s[i+1]
            i+=1

        q+=p*k
        #print(i,'second time')

print(q)
```

Answer (score -3):

what you want is not print substrings . the real purpose is most like to generate text based regular expression or comands.
you can parametrize a function to read it or use something like it:

The python library rstr has the function `xeger()` to do what you need by using random strings and only returning ones that match:

Example

```
Install with pip install rstr

In [1]: from __future__ import print_function

In [2]: import rstr

In [3]: for dummy in range(10):
   ...:     print(rstr.xeger(r"(a|b)[cd]{2}\1"))
   ...:
acca
bddb
adda
bdcb
bccb
bcdb
adca
bccb
bccb
acda
```

**Warning**
For complex re patterns this might take a long time to generate any matches.

Comment: How does this help anyone turn `'3(a)2(b)'` into `'aaabb'`?

Comment: If you're saying "you only need to turn your input string into a regex pattern that matches the output you're looking for, and then use xeger to turn the pattern into the output", that's a quite interesting approach, but you've sort of glossed over the "turn your input string into a regex pattern" bit. It's not too hard to manually turn `3(a)2(b)` into `a{3}b{2}`, but since the input varies, the OP probably needs a programmatic solution.

Comment: or you can change your input to some thing like that '1|a,3|b' and make a function that explodes , do a for and exploder each | get the number and string and make a complete string like you want.